# HTML access key (alt+s) not working from CK Editor

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

Im using CK Editor Version 4. I have a SAVE button and the CKEditor in the page.
I have given access key (s) to the 'Save' button.
I unable to save the contents of CK Editor using access key (alt+s). Is there any option to make access the html access key functionalities from CK Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below code for overriding/defining the shortcut for `save` command.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { });
editor.on('instanceReady', function( event ){
    editor.setKeystroke( [                  
        [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 83, 'save' ] // Alt+S
    ] );
});
```

If you are using more than one editor instance and you want them all to be affected, please simply put below code (starting from `CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady'` of course) into your `ckeditor\config.js` file. That way whenever editor instance is created it will be immediately equipped with the shortcut.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// global configuration settings go here....
};

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( event ){
    event.editor.setKeystroke( [                  
        [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 83, 'save' ] // Alt+S
    ] );
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the code not working, I have more than one CKeditor in a page. CK editor takes element id for initialization for this type of init CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1').  So I used to initialize by element class $('.editor1').ckeditor();

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have two options and one of them two has to work.